# getElementById() null error

Tags: javascript, alert, getelementbyid, textinput

For those who wants the soluce before the question :

1 ) Don't read an element with getElementById() before it's really created : see windows.onload.

2 ) If you are using XMLHTTPRequest and AJAX stuff, call you're getElementById() , or unlock this function, in the callback ,(xhr_object.readyState == 4 part of your request).

In my case, i call my page without using the desired callback (noobish Ctrl-C Ctrl-V style).

Here was the question :

I'm facing a strange case in a HTML/Javascript code.
The aim of this code is to get the value of an HTML input (type text) via a JS function.

The context is that a main HTML page loads my all my JS functions, and loads on demand HTML contents in sub divs via HTTPRequest.

The selected code is called after the divs has been loaded.

Here's the PHP generated Input field that i have to read:

```
    <input id="listejf" type="text" value="6|7|">
```

Here's my JavaScript call :

```
    listejf=document.getElementById('listejf').value;
    alert(listejf);
```

This code doesn't work. Firebug sends me:

> TypeError: document.getElementById("listejf") is null

The strange thing is that I can make it work if I call the `getElementById` through an `alert` like this:

```
    alert(document.getElementById("listejf"));
    listejf=document.getElementById('listejf').value;
    alert(listejf);
```

The first `alert` displays `null`, but the second one "6|7|", as expected.

Now, 2 questions:

- Why does alert make it work ?
- How can I make it work without throwing alerts everywhere?

Re-edit, the code was gone :

That's is the main HTML page : main.html

```
<head>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="./preload.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onCLick="CallPagen()">Link</a>
    <div id="targetid"></div>
</body>
```

preload.js looks like that :

```
function CallPagen() {
    envoieRequete('./PageN.php', 'targetid');
}

function mytestfunction() {
    listejf = document.getElementById('listejf').value;
    alert(listejf);
}

function envoieRequete(url, id) {
    var xhr_object = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) xhr_object = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhr_object.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr_object.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr_object.readyState == 4) {
            if (!document.getElementById(id)) {
                alert("id pas trouvé " + id);
            }
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = xhr_object.responseText;
            mytestfunction();
        }
    };
    xhr_object.send(null);
}
```

PageN.php just echoes the inputtext field with the value filled.

Comment: Make sure that your JavaScript comes **after** the `<input>` element on the page, or that it's in a "load" or "ready" handler.

Comment: The javascript code is loaded in my main page, before the element has been wrote, but this part of code is called after. I don't understand about handlers sry.

Comment: Well you haven't really posted enough context for the problem to be apparent. How exactly is the code called?

Comment: Does it happen with any browser? In addition we should see the main order of your code!

Comment: @Pointy: It's most likely that the xhr request is async.

Comment: @amnotiam yes probably, though again we're forced to solve a mystery here that could be easily clarified.

Comment: @Pointy: Yes, a little clarification is needed, but considering that OP is loading the content via xhr, and that the presence of an `alert` makes it work, I'd say it's about a 99% chance.

Comment: Well found, the alert gave the time to the input to be created :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"...I can make it work if i call the getelement through an `alert` like this..."*

This almost always means that you're making an ***asynchronous*** AJAX request.

> *"Why does alert make it work ?"*

What happens is that the `alert` delays the processing of the next line of code long enough for the response to return.

Without the `alert`, the next line of code runs immediately, and the element is not yet available.

> *"How can I make it work without throwing alerts everywhere?"*

This is a *very* common issue. The solution is that you need to put any code that *relies* on the response of the XMLHttpRequest request ***inside a callback*** to the request.

So if you're making a request through the native API, you'd add a `onreadystatechange` callback...

```
xhrRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhrRequest.readyState === 4) {
        // append the response text to the DOM

        listejf=document.getElementById('listejf').value;
        alert(listejf);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, there is no ajax included. Just the DOM asynchronous stuff

Comment: @Bergi: Huh? How do you know that?

Comment: I call the reading fonction in this way, but without result :[ . @am no i am : I just add some code in the main question ;) Thx all !

Comment: @encheridion: You're trying to select the content that you're loading via the HTTPRequest, right?

Comment: So that means in your callback you're adding the new content to the DOM, therefore you need to put your `getElementById` code in the same callback.

Comment: @am not i am : I managed to reupload my code (sorry about the indentation :s) It's look like i do what you are suggesting.

Comment: @encheridion: And did you verify that your response contains an element with the ID `"listejf"`? There's nothing in your code that would cause the `alert` to have any effect. Are you posting the original code that was giving you trouble?

Comment: Yes, here is the real one : <input id="listejf" value="7|" type="text">

Comment: @encheridion: Is the code you posted the same code you were using when you originally asked the question? Is there any code we're missing?

Comment: @amnotiam: Sorry, I haven't seen that in the first version of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should run the code after DOM is ready, when the `alert()` is called, document is loading and browser has time for creating the DOM objects, try the following:

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var listejf = document.getElementById('listejf').value;
    alert(listejf);
};
```

Comment: Seen that the creation of the input is made via XMLHttpRequest, window.onload seems to don't trigger as expected. Thanks for the try !

Comment: @encheridion You are welcome, as you are using Ajax you should run the code after ajax is complete.